# Explanation for radial elongation in rotating bodies

Tags: reference-frames, inertial-frames, centrifugal-force

Why does a rotating body, like a rod or a spring, exhibit elongation instead of compression even though every part of it experiences "centri-seeking" force? Is it plausible to understand this in an inertial frame of reference, rather than the conventional pseudo refrence frame?

Answer (score 0):

The force on the furthest element of the spring  due to the rest of the spring is radially inwards and causes the centripetal acceleration of the furthest.

The force on the rest of the spring due to the furthest element of the spring is radially outwards - Newton’s third law.
A force radially outwards will elongate the rest of the spring.

The sequence can then be repeated for the penultimate element etc.
Thus each element of the spring will have two forces acting on it: a force which is radially inwards on the side which is closer to the centre of rotation and a smaller force which is radially outwards on the side further from the centre of rotation.
The net inward force on the element causes the centripetal acceleration of the element and the two tensile forces are responsible for elongating the spring.

Answer (score 0):

You might be confusing centripetal force and [centrifugal force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrifugal_force). It's the latter that is considered a fictitious force in Newtonian physics and can be seen as the cause of the radial elongation.

For example in a top loader washing machine, the clothes that are originally near the center, stick to the outer wall when the machine starts rapidly rotating.

An easy way to see why a rotating body would radially elongate would be to not look at it from a force perspective but rather from angular momentum.

For a particle in a circular orbit under the influence of a centripetal force (I'm assuming it to be gravity), the angular momentum $L$  is

$$ L = m r^2 \omega  = m \sqrt{GMr}\,,$$

$\omega$ being the angular and $M$ is the central sources mass.

So from the above, if the objects rotates faster, then $L$ goes up. But since $L \propto \sqrt{r}$, so $r$ has to increase as well (for the object to remain in a circular orbit).